# What do the Catholics say about Isaiah 29:13?

Tags: catholicism, rosary

Isaiah 29:13 NLT reads:

> ... And their worship of me
>       is nothing but man-made rules learned by rote.

I come from a Catholic background. And we are taught the Rosary and many such prayers by rote learning. Does this not contradict the above verse?

Comment: Did Jesus contradict the above verse, when He taught His disciples to say the Lord's Prayer ?

Comment: A good rule of thumb (which is why this isn't an answer) is that Catholic doctrine (and likely many other denomination's) rarely hangs upon a single verse.

Comment: Christ gave Peter and the other apostles authority to make rules ("Whatsoever you bind on earth shall be bound in heaven"), whereas the rule-makers of Isaiah's time had no such authority.

Comment: I voted to reopen without looking at the whole of the answer to the intended duplicate (*my* answer :-|) I take that vote back.